# Spyder startup trouble

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have troubles to start Spyder.
This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 7, in 
from spyder.app.start import main
File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 27, in 
from spyder.config.main import CONF
File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/config/main.py", line 22, in 
from spyder.config.user import UserConfig
File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/config/user.py", line 26, in 
from spyder.utils.programs import check_version
File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/programs.py", line 18, in 
import subprocess
File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in 
import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __Py_set_inheritable_async_safe
Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

Somebody have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: try the solution suggested in this gitHub [issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6876)

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this you need to open Terminal.app and run there

`conda update python python.app spyder`

Comment: @GiancanioSileo, glad to know! Please mark the answer as correct by selecting the green check mark above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

run 
`conda update --all`

can solve this problem！

Comment: hi, while your method might solve the OP's problem it would be better to post suggestions as comments.